# How can i fix Cannot implicitly convert Generic.List< > to Generic.List< >

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can i fix Cannot implicitly convert `System.Collections.Generic.List <RPHistory>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List <RPHistory>` exception error.

I am trying to combine two Entities together to get a single list

RP Entity Class:

```
 public class RP 
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int RPID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int ProductID { get; set; }
        }
```

RPHistory Entity Class :

```
public class RPHistory: 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int RPID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }
```

And I created this third class

RpWithHistory Class :

```
public class RpWithHistory {
  public int ID;
  public int RPID;
  public string Name;
  public int ProductID;

  public List<RPHistory> History;
}
```

Linq Query

```
var RPs = await Context.RP.Where(b => b.ProductID  == request.ID)
                              .Select(x=> new RpWithHistory {
                                               ID = x.ID, 
                                               RPID = x.RPID, 
                                               Name = x.Name, 
                                               ProductID = x.ProductID, 
                                               History = Context.RPHistory
                                                                .Where(y=> y.RPID 
                                                                        == x.RPID)
                                                                .ToList()
                                               }
                                      ).ToListAsync();
```

But i get this error,

```
>Cannot implicitly convert System.Collections.Generic.List <RPHistory> to
>System.Collections.Generic.List <RPHistory> exception error
```

Thanks!

Comment: `public List<RPHistory> History;` is a property or a variable?

Comment: @mvermef Thanks  its a property

Comment: Are you sure both RPHistory types are really the same types? If you right click the types and choose "go to definition" do they point to the same place? If so, I don't see why any error would be shown

Comment: the fact that both RP and RPHistory are identical is weird in of itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you're doing that. Can I suggest this?

You do not need to go all that way of creating a class that joins the two. Just create a Navigation property on your RP that points to RPHistory Objects.

```
public class RP 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RPID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RPHistory> HistoryList { get; set; } // Navigation Property
}

public class RPHistory: 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RPID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RPID))] // Identify the Foreign Key from RP Class
    public RP RP { get; set; } // Navigation back to RP
}
```

Then you can chain everything into a single list using LINQ:

```
var RPs = Context.RP.Where(rp => rp.ProductID  == request.ID)
                 .Include(rp=>rp.RPHistory) // This includes RPHistory
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: But one thing looking the log it inner joins INNER JOIN [dbo].[RPHistory] AS [r] ON [v].[ProductID] = [r].[RPID] - I want to join when ProductID=ProdcutID

Comment: You want to join when RP ProductID equals RPHistory ProductID? I don't understand there.

Comment: Yes, Mosia, thats what i want but ProductID is not a primary key in both tables. Thanks! yo make my day by the way :)

Comment: Are RPID's different? Because if RPID's are the same, then you don't have to apply ProductID, EF will by Default use RPID foreignKey to fetch RPHistory Objects based on RPID... I would always suggest using any defining property as the commonality between two tables because then it becomes easier. Based on the design of the Tables, I don't think RPID's would be the same while ProductID's would be different, or am I wrong?

Comment: RPID's  are different. productID must be the same in RP and RP history table in order to show them but different RPID's , RPHistory table stores  deleted rps

Comment: RPID's  are always different in two tables but same ProductID. ProductID must be the same in RP and RP history table in order to show them/join the two.  for your question yes always different RPID's but the same ProductID. RPHistory is Just to show who was there before it just for a reference purpose

Comment: Ok awesome, here's what we can do. Make ProductID your Primary Key with [Key] so that it can act as your Joining Field... So your ID on RP can just be an Identity Column(Although I don't see the value of having both). And even if you do that , he query will still work but now using ProductID as your PK in RP and as ForeignKey in RPHistory. Previously I wasn't sure which was the Primary Key... lol!

Comment: lol Thanks, i tried that but  why it is keep saying Invalid column name 'ProductID '? It looks like Sql join in the log is right

Comment: That's Funny, I wonder why it's saying that. It would be great to check if that column exists in your schema. Are you using Model First approach when creating your database?

Comment: Yes, I have Entity configuration with mapping and created DTO for each entity. I think i have see the same before i will take a look. Thank so much for your help!!!.

Comment: Mosia, Can you do me a favor, How can i change .Include to union?, Sorry to bother

Comment: You can't replace Include with Union... Union Joins same Entities given that they were either filtered with different criateria, or whatever the case may be, while Include includes a sub-entity/child entity to the parent entity

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone or create a new list.

Option 1: Use ConvertAll

```
List<RPHistory> pPHistoryCopy = rphWithHistory.RPHistory.ConvertAll(history => new RPHistory(rphWithHistory.RPHistory));
```

Option 2:

```
//Clone Extension
static class Extensions
{
    public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> listToClone) where T: ICloneable
    {
        return listToClone.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Use the clone extention

Comment: Thanks, where can i use ConvertAll that after the linq?